# Yii2: Is it possible to disable breadcrumbs in some case (mobile for example)

Tags: yii2, breadcrumbs

As the title said, I want in some case to hide or disable the breadcrumbs in my Yii2 app.
Is there any general solution or should I put code in any of my view?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually find this solution :

First add a param in the app config/params.php : 'ariane'

```
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com', 
    'bsVersion' => '3.x',
    'ariane' => false,
];
```

then add code to empty the links array conditionally in the layout main.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset(Yii::$app->params['ariane']) && Yii::$app->params['ariane'] == false){
     $this->params['breadcrumbs'] = [];
  }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to put breadcrumb in layout and check it for condition only once.

I mean this way in layout file:

```
<?php if ($condition) {
    Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]); 
} ?>
<?= $content ?> //view file content
```

Comment: yes but it's just a detail, I'm starting with Yii and I was mainly looking for the empty array code solution. As the param would probably be replace by a Session variable depending of mobile or not, admin or not etc...